# How to Know ClickOnce's Registry Uninstall Key before installing it

Tags: registry, clickonce

I want to check if certain clickonce app is already installed or not ...

The easiest way is to check:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*UnInstallID*

But I have no clue about retrieve (via ".manifest" etc.) the *UnInstallID* from certain ClickOnce App from Repository.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can programmatically read through the keys in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall and check the DisplayName on each key. This will match the Product Name of the ClickOnce application. If you find a match, it's installed.

If you can have multiple versions of the same application installed, you can also check the DisplayVersion, and/or search the Uninstall string for a matching public key token.